# mysql source command using variable name for script

Tags: mysql

I have two script for mysql:

crt_db_small.sql

crt_db_large.sql

I would like to be able to use a varible to set which script gets run with mysql.

I have tried the following:

```
set @sname := 'crt_db_large.sql';

source @sname ;
```

But this errors with:

`ERROR: Failed to open file '@sname', error: 2`

Similarly, I'd also like to use a variable with `use dbname` command:

```
set @db := 'devdb';

use @db;
```

This also errors with:

`Unknown database '@db'`

The bigger aim here is to have scripts that can be deployed to any environment without having to change them.

So we would have a  'settingsXXX.sql' file, where XXX is the environment name, and when running 'deplopyXXX.sql' would reference this,m and all scripts that get called by deployXXXX.sql simply refer to the variables for things like database name in the `use` command.

Is there a way to do this in mysql.

Comment: look for dynamic sql

Comment: #1. `SOURCE` is not SQL statement but client command. You cannot execute it as SQL statement. #2. `USE` accepts the parameter literally. Use dynamic SQL.

Comment: Use dynamic sql and use the database name in the script itself